# Проблемы с кодировкой (возможно двойная кодировка)

Tags: кодировка, перекодировка

Сделал бекап сайта на хостинге ukraine, установил его - сбилась кодировка у кириллических файлов. Откатить обратно возможности нет, нужно найти способ декодировать обратно названия.

Что имеем: 
Исходное название файла: Доповідач-ПАРЄ
Получившееся название: ¦Ф¦-¦¬¦-¦-TЦ¦+¦-TЗ-¦Я¦Р¦а¦Д

Есть догадка что произошла двойная смена кодировки, известные мне инструменты (онлайн декореды) не помогли.

Comment: Судя по повторяющимся символам | - там был unicode, но испортился. Попробуйте поиграть в декодорах вариантами, зная, что результат должен быть в unicode.

Comment: Изменяйте подход к хранению файлов. Имена файлов не должны содержать символов с кодами выше 7F. Если вы хотите отдавать пользователю такие названия, то храните их в базе (названия), имена файлов на сервере формируйте как хеш от реального или по другим правилам с сопоставлением в базе.